# Prove $\sqrt[n]{-z^nw}=-z\sqrt[n]{w}$ for complex numbers, if $n$ odd

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z$ and $w$ be complex numbers and $n$ an odd natural number. Prove that
$$\sqrt[n]{-z^nw}=-z\sqrt[n]{w}.$$
**Try:**

Let $z=r_1(\cos(\varphi_1)+i\sin(\varphi_1))$ and $w=r_2(\cos(\varphi_2)+i\sin(\varphi_2))$. Then
$$-z^n=-r_1^n(\cos(n\varphi_1)+i\sin(n\varphi_1)),$$
$$-z^nw=-r_1^nr_2(\cos(n\varphi_1+\varphi_2)+i\sin(n\varphi_1+\varphi2))$$
and
$$\sqrt[n]{-z^nw}=\left\{-r_1\sqrt[n]{r_2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{n\varphi_1+\varphi_2+2k\pi}{n}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{n\varphi_1+\varphi_2+2k\pi}{n}\right)\right)\mid k=\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}\right\}.$$
On the other hand
$$-z\sqrt[n]{w}=-z\cdot\left\{\sqrt[n]{r_2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\varphi_2+2k\pi}{n}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\varphi_2+2k\pi}{n}\right)\right)\mid k=\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}\right\}$$
$$=\left\{-r_1\sqrt[n]{r_2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{n\varphi_1+\varphi_2+2k\pi}{n}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{n\varphi_1+\varphi_2+2k\pi}{n}\right)\right)\mid k=\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}\right\}.$$
Therefore $\sqrt[n]{-z^nw}=-z\sqrt[n]{w}$.

Is this correct or am I way off?

Comment: Your problem is not well defined.  For example, if $z$ is any non-zero complex number, and $(n)$ is any positive integer $~ > 1, ~$ the expression $z^{(1/n)}$ ambiguously refers to the $~n~$ **different** $(n)$-th roots of $z$.  Before attacking the problem, you must specify the exact algorithm that is to be used to resolve the ambiguity.  You should not force the MathSE reviewer to *reverse-engineer* the pertinent algorithm from the analysis in your posted *solution*.

Comment: It *is* well defined. It is clear from this post that no "algorithm" is involved and that $\sqrt[n]~$ denotes the *multivalued* function "set of $n$-th roots".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct but might be shortened: let (with your notation) $$u\in\sqrt[n]w.$$Then, $(-zu)^n=(-1)^nz^nu^n=-z^nw$ hence
$$\sqrt[n]{-z^nw}=\{-zuv\mid v^n=1\}=-z\{uv\mid v^n=1\}=-z\sqrt[n]w.$$

Comment: See my comment, following the original posting.

Comment: @user2661923 See my comment under yours.

Comment: "You should not force the MathSE reviewer to reverse-engineer the pertinent algorithm from the analysis in your posted solution." : It seems that you had to read the analysis to reverse engineer what the OP intended.

Comment: No I hadn't: it was clear to me as soon as I read the title, because it couldn't mean anything else.

Comment: Untrue.  Looking only at the title, there was no way of determining that the OP intended some unambiguous convention for determing (for example) the $n$th root of some non-zero complex number $(z)$.  In fact, to the best of my knowledge, there is no such universally agreed unambiguous definition of $z^{(1/n)}.$  This implies that while you were focusing only on the title, you were forced to assume that the OP had some sensible, valid idea in mind.  Even then, you had no way of knowing what that idea might be, or whether the OP was properly applying the idea.  ...see next comment

Comment: It was only when your focus shifted away from the title, were you able to become confident that the OP had a sensible idea that the OP might or might not be validly applying.